# Team Foundation shows items as checked out after checking in

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2012

I have a website with several thousand pages that I have added to TFS source control.  I have created a workspace with the local path mapping to the actual file directory (so that anytime a file is saved, the actual source file is saved as well).  I have added my files and then checked them in.

After checking them in for the first time I see the lock symbol next to all of the files.  Now if I go to check out and edit, I can check in my changes and this shows up in the changeset, but the file remains checked out.  I can view the history and see all iterations (every time it was checked in), but it still always shows the file as checked out.

I think the issue may have something to do with the fact that I created the workspace as a particular user and then made it a Public Workspace.  I now am logged in as a different user attempting to check in/out.

I also just noticed that in my history it shows the changes made by UserB, but in Source Control Explorer it shows checked out by UserA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating this project I set my workspace to the initial source code directory.  I then set another user's workspace to this same directory (it was a shared drive).  Visual Studio did not stop me from doing this because this local path was set on different computers, but I believe that this was the issue.